# Action hook on only publishing post not on editing or updating

Tags: actions

Could you please let me know wordpress action hook that must triggered only once when a user create a new custom post.

That means if user creates a new post that hook must be triggered but when user update or edit the post then that hook should not be executed.

Previously i was using publish_post but it always executed when user create, edit or update the post however i have added some conditions to prevent this action but didn't works for me.

The code is as follow:

```
add_action( 'publish_property', 'pms_post_published_notification', 10, 2 );


    function pms_post_published_notification( $ID, $post ) {
         if(get_post_field('post_type',$ID ) === 'property' && !wp_is_post_revision( $ID )){// custom code here}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `new_to_publish` action as described on [Post Status Transitions](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions) Codex page (updated according @prog comment):

```
add_action( 'new_to_publish', 'pms_post_published_notification', 10, 1 );

function pms_post_published_notification( $post ) {
    if( 'property' === $post->post_type ) {
        // custom code here
    }
}
```

The only argument is passed to your function is `$post` object, so you can utilize it to check the post type.

- [Post Status Transitions](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions)
- [{$old_status}_to_{$new_status}](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/old_status_to_new_status/) action

Comment: thanks @Max but its not working. however i have used new_to_publish but it still not working

Comment: Touche. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can always make use of the more global [`transition_post_status`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/transition_post_status/) action hook which fires on every transition status for all post types.

Three values are passed by reference to the hook

- `$new_status` which is the post status the post will have after transition
- `$old_status` which is the post status the post had before transitioning
- `$post` which is the current post object of the post being transitioned

Because a new post does not have any concrete set old post status, and definitely does not have an old status of publish, we can use that as logic to test against and then run our custom code based on that

```
add_action( 'transition_post_status', function ( $new_status, $old_status, $post )
{
    if (    'publish' === $new_status
         && 'publish' !== $old_status
         && 'property' === $post->post_type
    ) {
        // This is a new property post, lets do some work
        // Run your custom code here
    }
}, 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Not wanting to be a smart*ss @Pieter, but does a (new)post which will be created not directly get a `post_status` of `auto-draft`? (and if, than it must be sure that `transition_post_status` this not ignores?)

Comment: Sorry for only coming back now, I was stuck with my mobile, and for some unknown crappy reason I cannot post comments from my mobile. Yes, it is true that posts get assigned as `auto-draft`, but we cannot go on this. What happens if we click safe draft and come back later to publish it. Our status is not `auto-draft` anymore, but only `draft`. Also, `future` posts are also a new post when it finally get published. Checking if the previous status is not published is a more reliable way to do this as this will take care of `future`, `draft` and `auto-draft`

Comment: Thank you @Pieter for the explanation, I am still struggling with this and your response makes it a little brighter at the horizon.

Comment: So you want to say that I have to cycle through all (any) transitions. And than each of them to check Post Types?
May be  `define('WP_POST_REVISIONS', false );` are set.

If not, the transition will be false.

Comment: @MaxYudin No, what I have posted is exactly what `new_to_publish` and `publish_property` does. My code is just more generic and much more flexible as it is not bound to one specific aspect. You can copy my code as-is and test it

Comment: Yes, I see now.

Answer (score 0):

However the below given code works for me.

```
add_action( 'new_to_publish', 'pms_post_published_notification', 10, 1 );

function pms_post_published_notification( $post ) {
    if($post->post_type == 'property') {
        // custom code here
    }
}
```

Thanks @Max